# Calculate Yearly Quarter

Tags: sharepoint-online, calculated-column-formula, date

Trying to create a column that will determine the financial quarter that a date field currently represents.

The 1st quarter should always begin on November 1st.

Current formula:

```
=IF(ISBLANK([Actual Date]),"",(CONCATENATE("Q"&(INT((MONTH([Actual Date])-1)/3)+1)&" "&(YEAR([Actual Date])))))
```

> ((MONTH([Actual Date])-1)/3)+1)

How would I amend this to make Q1 start on November 1st?

As always, any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: This post looks like it might be useful for you: https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/173588/calculating-a-fiscal-quarter-from-a-date     There are other similar posts, try searching under the [calculated-column] or [calculated-column-formula] tags

Comment: That post is what I've based my formula on. I had already searched for previous questions of a similar fashion but there are not many relating to financial quarter calculations.

Comment: Hi Jim, did this work for you in the end?  If so could you mark as Answered please?  ta, Tally

Comment: Apologies Tally, I tested this solution but ended up calculating the Quarter using a site workflow instead.

Answer (score 2):

You could try this instead, to calculate accidents I need to use a reporting year which runs from 01/11/2017 - 31/10/2018.  Happily, we both have the same reporting year/financial year.

We need to create some calculated fields and some 'single line of text' fields.

**YEAR**

To split off the year data, create a 'single line of text' field with the formula below:

```
=""&YEAR([Accident Date])
```

- Instead of 'Accident Date' you would use your field called 'Actual Date'.

**MONTH**

To split off the month data, create a 'single line of text' field with the formula below:

```
=TEXT([Accident Date],"mm")
```

Again you use your 'Actual Date' field instead of my [Accident Date].

**PERIOD**

Next make a new 'single line of text' field called PERIOD.  You would call this field Quarter instead of Period.  Formula:

```
=IF(Month<"11",Year,TEXT(Year+1,"0"))
```

What is this doing?  It looks at the Month field, if Month is 11 or more, it grabs the Year value and does +1 that calculates my reporting year.  Otherwise if Month is less than 11 add +0 to the Year field, so keep it the same.

**For your solution (??)**

You'd need to modify the **Period** formula to make a Quarter calculation: this is the important bit, but I don't know how to do it.  I believe it can be done in a single formula, with the 'quarter query' nestled within the brackets.  The syntax is tricky though...

So begin with the Period formula and adapt...sorry I can't help with the final part, but I hope this answer sends you in the right direction...